# Plotly v4 VSCode Jupyter notebook how to use Scatter.on_selection() callback

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, plotly-python

Python 3.10

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def cb(*arg):
    print(arg)
    
fig = go.FigureWidget([list(px.scatter(df,'Z1','Z2', color='Metra').select_traces())[0]])

fig.data[0].on_selection(cb)
fig.data[0].on_click(cb)

assert isinstance(fig, plotly.graph_objs.FigureWidget)

fig.show()
```

The call-back does not execute when running the cell and making selections or clicking on the figure. How can I get it to work? *I have Jupyter Notebook Renderers installed, which might override some plotly behavior.

package versions:
IPython          : 8.5.0
ipykernel        : 6.16.0
ipywidgets       : 8.0.2
jupyter_client   : 7.4.2
jupyter_core     : 4.11.1
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.7.0
nbconvert        : 7.2.3
nbformat         : 5.7.0
notebook         : not installed
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.4.0